# Copy a list of files with absolute paths and wildcards preserving the source path in the destination

Tags: command-line, bash, copy

I want to copy files listed in a text file with absolute paths to another folder preserving the folder tree in the destination.

in2.txt:

```
//PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/top_surface/nok/220104/inner_rim_220110T070720.*
//PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/top_surface/nok/220104/inner_rim_220110T064927*
//PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/top_surface/nok/220104/inner_rim_220110T070210.xml
```

I want the source folder tree preserved within the output folder.

```
outd=/cygdrive/c/0/out27/
rsync -vR --include-from=in2.txt / $outd
```

results in the following and copies nothing:

```
$   rsync -vR --include-from=in2.txt / $outd
skipping directory /.
sent 17 bytes  received 12 bytes  19.33 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

trying cp with --parents:

```
while read p; do
  cp --parents "$p" $outd  # i had problem with unc path  //corp-fs01
done <in2.txt
```

Yields..

```
//PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/top_surface/nok/220104/inner_rim_220110T070210.xml
cp: failed to get attributes of '/PMDA-SO5632': No such file or directory
```

How can I achieve the copy?
It doesn't have to be rsync or cp.

Comment: what are you coping and why?

Comment: you need to leave $p unquoted or the wildcards wont expand (`read -r` kind of mandatory).

Answer (score 1):

Don't think the `-R` attribute does what you intend to do. Usually, the archive attribute is enough. Rsync acts on the first rule that matches. And those objects not matching any rule will **not** be skipped and should be exclusively excluded.

```
rsync -va --include-from=in2.txt --exclude='*' / $outd
```

Parent directories have to be included too, or they will be excluded by `'*'`, and rsync won't recursively traverse the directory structure.

```
/PMDA-SO5632/
/PMDA-SO5632/data/
/PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/
/PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/
/PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/top_surface/
/PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/top_surface/nok/
/PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/top_surface/nok/220104/
/PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/top_surface/nok/220104/inner_rim_220110T070720.*
/PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/top_surface/nok/220104/inner_rim_220110T064927*
/PMDA-SO5632/data/vision_6830/image_data/top_surface/nok/220104/inner_rim_220110T070210.xml
```

Another solution would be to expand all file objects inside in2.txt before processed by rsync and use `--files-from=` instead. It will only copy objects included in the file without having to add any additional parent directories.

```
rsync < in2.txt -va --files-from=- / $outd
```